# handling finger detection on small objects

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, detection

The application I am working on requires a 4px bar height with a full screen size width. I need to be able to select this 4px bar and move it around. I also can not change the size of this bar it has to be 4px in height.

This wouldn't be that big of an issue if I wasn't using OpenGL to create the object. OpenGL obviously does not have its own selection features so I am needing to program my own.

Initially after research I built a color selector to identify the object. How my color selector works is what ever `x` and `y` my finger touch returns from `touchesBegan:` is the pixel I grab from a screenshot of the OpenGL View. The issue with this is finger location is not precise at all. If I use the mouse it works perfect...

I decided to maybe loop through a buffer zone of the selected `x` and `y` but unfortunately a screenshot of the OpenGL view has antialiasing happens to the image when it's stored in memory and the buffer returns several shade of my objects color. I could possibly do a comparative color look up, to see if its in the range of colors but that seems overly complicated with how much I have already had to do. Plus cycling through the buffer zone isn't quick.

I also have thought maybe just remembering the location of my line on the screen and if my finger is close to that location just know that that's the one I want to select and move it around.

The future of this application can have up to 4 lines just like this so, I want something more secure then just knowing the location of where it is in memory.

What better way is there out there of handling selection of small objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about maintaining an array of frames for the four objects, but expand the heights to something more manageable (8px or bigger)?  Then, a touch within the larger region could be compared against the array (using CGRectContainsPoint).  If you get a hit, then "snap to" the center point of the smaller (4px) rectangle before beginning the drag.

I do something like this by maintaining a list of "drop targets" for drag & drop, where it snaps to the drop target when it gets pretty close.  Don't know if I'm conveying the idea very well, but it ought to work.

If the four 4px rectangles are going to be contiguous or very close together, you'll have to be able to make the selected one stand out or the user won't be able to tell which they're dragging -- but you could do that by making it bigger (maybe 6-8 px) then bringing it to the front so it overlays its adjacent neighbors.

More of an idea than an answer I guess.

Answer (score 1):

John,

I would suggest a different approach. As you've discovered, touches in iOS are **very** imprecise. Apple usually suggests that the "hit box" for your controls be at least 40x40 points. I've gone as small as 30x30 points, but that starts to get hard.

What I would suggest you do is to factor your code so the app knows where the line is, and keeps track of it as a logical object. Then in your touch handler, interpret touches based on a large "buffer area" around the things you want the user to be able to move. If you just have a single horizontal bar, this should work great. Where you'll get into trouble is if you have multiple, thin horizontal bars that are close together. In that case you might need to rethink your app design and find another way to solve the problem.

As for the implementation details, you might add a pan gesture recognizer to your OpenGL view, and have it notify the OpenGL view of touch and drag actions. Then your OpenGL view can use knowledge of where your draggable objects are to decide how to interpret the touches.

Comment: Luckily we switched to CoreGraphics/Quartz and things became a lot easier. Also what I was trying to accomplish has been thrown out as an iOS feature and is now only the web apps feature. Thanks for the answer though!